# Excel 2013 access violation 0xC0000005

Tags: c++, com, access-violation, excel-2013

I have a problem with an old piece of software (early 2000) written in C++ that uses Excel for processing data. It worked fine in previous versions of Excel but since version 2013, I get a crash that I haven't seen before.

We have created our own COM add-in for Excel, this add-in is registered with regsvr32 and available in Excel 2013. The add-in refused to work at first but disabling Data Execution Prevention (DEP) got it working.

This add-in is accessed by creating an instance of Excel in code:

```
_Application.CreateDispatch ("Excel.Application");
```

After creating the instance of Excel we get the loaded add-ins from the instance and find our add-in by looping through the COM add-ins.

```
_Application.GetCOMAddIns();
```

Once we got our add-in we can send commands through the interface:

```
IExcelServer* server = excel.GetServerAddIn();      // Obtain the server COM-AddIn.
HRESULT result = server->Execute (&req, &rep, &retval);
```

One of the commands we can send here is requesting a value from Excel based on a given string label (the label will be in column A and this function returns the value in column B on the same row). Now the code crashes on the following line of code:

```
rng.Find (COleVariant (label), CovOptional, CovOptional, COleVariant (xlWhole), CovOptional, xlSearchNext, CovOptional, CovOptional, CovOptional);
```

The 'rng' object is of type Range and is from the correct sheet and the range goes from A1 to A17. When we get the value from 'rng' object (rng.GetValue2()) it gives us the following array (which contains the value that is specified in the label argument):

safearray of VARIANT = [1,17](Empty,Empty,BSTR = 0x160bc6bc "Web",Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,BSTR = 0x0bbca5cc "Pre",BSTR = 0x15f499fc "WebStart",BSTR = 0x0bbca48c "WebMid",BSTR = 0x0bbca5a4 "WebEnd",BSTR = 0x160bc80c "Post",Empty,Empty,BSTR = 0x15f49a24 "SafeStartWeb",BSTR = 0x15f49a4c "SafeEndWeb",Empty)

We receive the following error while debugging:

*"Unhandled Exception at 0x00ccbb4A in Excel.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000."*

We also see the following message in the windows event viewer every time that Excel crashes:

*"The description for Event ID 0 from source MSOIDSVC.EXE cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.*

*If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.*

*The following information was included with the event:*

*InitializeSvcAPI failed with hr = 0x8004888d"*

The code is made in VS2010 using C++ and running Windows7 x64. We have also tested the code on a Windows8 x64 machine but we got the same result.

Has someone seen this crash before or can advise how to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This kind of crash is caused by insufficient error checking.  Plenty of evidence of that in the very brief snippets.  Some kind of COM call failed, you get a NULL pointer and dereference it anyway.  Kaboom.  Sure, the event log entry may well be very significant.

Comment: @HansPassant How can we improve our error checking? We are calling the COM function rng.Find(..). The Range class is "machine generated IDispatch wrapper" from Excel. When we call the function Excel crashes and we receive the error as mentioned above during debugging. We do not get a result from the call (like a NULL pointer).